# Smaller div tags in one large one not centering or spanning across screen

Tags: html, css, iframe

Ok, so I am making a website for my so far small Minecraft Build team MCBuild, unfortunately, My ribbon on the top with all the pages links, that are not active, will not centered it is embedded inside of another div, and put into a singular .html file and displayed through an iFrame. All of the code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/MCBuild/mcbuild.github.io) and also, the page can be viewed [here](https://mcbuild.github.io). Any help would be great, I think I can't get it just because I am frustrated that I didn't get it the first time. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the relevant markup and css to the question as links can change overtime.

Comment: On `div#ribbon` you could just `text-align: center`. Which will center the anchor tags.